# What is the significance of kafka configuration. auto.create.topic.enable?

Tags: apache-kafka

When I try to change the config auto.create.topic.enable to false and then i try to produce some message to a topic which does not exist.

It gives me the error that this topic is not available but it still creates a topic and sends the data to that topic.

We can later consume the data also from that topic? 
So what is the significance of this config(auto.create.topic.enable) if setting it to false also letting the producer create a new topic?

Answer (score 2):

What Kafka version are you using ? the broker should not create the topic if `auto.create.topic.enable` is set to false.

Comment: its kafka 0.10.0.2.5.3.0-37

Comment: can you give it a try to 1.0.0 version ?